# How do scoring and indexing work together in Information Retrieval Systems

Tags: machine-learning, solr, lucene, information-retrieval, tf-idf

I have a brief understanding of indexing ( inverse indexing ) and scoring ( like tf-idf ) in IR . Generally , if there is no indexing , a tf-idf matrix is pre-calculated , and a corresponding tf-idf vector is made for the query and then scores calculated for each document .

What is this flow like when there is indexing done for the documents , specifically how does a library like apache lucene or terrier process a query to evaluate scores for documents .

Answer (score 2):

Lucene [uses BM25 now](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25), which has a modified slope compared to the old practical tf/idf scoring formula.

When you index documents (putting them into the Lucene index), each field is broken into tokens. How that happens and what is being considered a token depends on the definition of the field. For example if you decide to tokenize on whitespace and apply a lowercase filter, the value "Foo Bar" will be stored as two tokens, `foo` and `bar`. If you do not apply any tokenization (or use the KeywordTokenizer) and does not apply any filters, you'll get one token - `Foo Bar`).

The same process happens when you make a query. The query sent to the field is tokenized and filtered according to the rules for that field, so if you search for `fOO bAR` in the above example, the query consist of two tokens after processing: `foo` and `bar`.

The score for the document is then calculated according to these tokens with the BM25 formula. If you take a look at the formula, you can see that the score is calculated for each token (q), then summed up to get a score for the field.

[image: BM25 scoring formula from Wikipedia]

If you add `debugQuery=true` after a query to Solr, you'll get detailed information about exactly how the score is being calculated.